# Vim 'Project' plugin - "Not enough room" when performing a project-wide grep

Tags: vim, plugins, project

The extremely useful "Project" plugin offers a project-wide grep via shortcuts `\g \G`. When I try to use this on a project of reasonable size, I receive output:

```
Error detected while processing function <SNR>20_GrepAll
line 21:
Not enough room.
```

I've searched vim help for a solution and haven't come up with anything thus far.

Does anyone know the cause of this, and whether there's a quick remedy available, perhaps via some option in my .vimrc?

Answer (score 0):

You might have not enough memory. Try:

```
:vimgrep /SEARCHSTRING/j /path/to/project/**/YOURFILEPATTERN
```

Right after issue a `:copen`, to open the list of files in the `quickfix` window!

*Note*, the `**` helps you to search recursively in your project dir.

Comment: This sounds great Zsolt but sadly doesn't work; it complains about the ** recursive indicator. Can you spot your mistake?

Comment: What you mean by complaining?

Comment: `:vimgrep /test.log/j /home/projects/myproj/**/` outputs `"myproj/**/" Illegal file name.`

Comment: Yes because that's not a filename. Try `/home/projects/myproj/**/*` instead.

Comment: That solves the problem, thank you. However no results show, yet what I'm searching for is definitely in many files in the project. Should I expect the search results to appear in a new window inside vim?

Comment: Vim is supposed to jump to the first result, to see all the result you must type `:copen`.

Comment: @romainl No, with `j` flag after pattern presented here it is not supposed to jump anywhere.

Comment: OK, I totally missed `j`. No jumping, then.